# what is smallmoney data type unit in sql server?

Tags: sql-server

smallmoney data type in sql server makes me confuse.

after creating a table and add a columns with this data type, i entered a number(one) and it shows me this:

```
 1.0000
```

what is this means?this means is one dollar or one cent?
if i want to store one cent i should enter what?

```
 this 0.1 or 1.0000 and if is correct what about entering one dollar?
```

i want to store some things like this one dollar and 55 cent.

Comment: It is a fixed precision number accurate to ten thousandths of the 'monetary unit' so could be a dollar or pound etc but if you need more precision then it could represent a cent or penny etc. its up to you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`smallmoney` is just like `money`, but smaller. Specifically `money` is an 8 bit `Decimal`, whereas `smallmoney` is a 4 bit `Decimal`. [Source](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179882.aspx)

Further, your question on what does `1.000` represent, it can represent what you want. Again from the source

> Use a period to separate partial monetary units, like cents, from whole monetary units. For example, 2.15 specifies 2 dollars and 15 cents.

Presumably you could consider `2.15` to mean 2.15 million, just deal with it appropriately when you handle the data

Answer (score 0):

`smallmoney` is `decimal`.

Have a look at [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc716729%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
SQL-Server-type    .NET-type    SqlDbType     SqlDataReader 
smallmoney         Decimal      SmallMoney    GetSqlMoney
```